# PDO-ODBC (MS SQL) returns NULL results

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, centos

I make the connection like so:

```
$dbh = new PDO ("odbc:DRIVER=MSODBC17;SERVER=$hostname,$port;DATABASE=$dbname", "$username", "$pw");
```

Then query:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("
   --QUERY HERE
");
$stmt->execute();
```

And when I print it, it returns `NULL`

```
//var_dump($stmt->fetch());

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

---

The connection doesn't throw any errors, so I'm guessing it's successful.

How come I get `NULL` as output then?

Comment: seams like you should learn about SQL query, your query miss at least the FROM statement to define on which table you're querying

Comment: @MacBooc The query that I'm using is not the one thats here...the same query has worked in the past.

Comment: so try with adding the mode like `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` in the fetch function

Comment: @MacBooc `$stmt->PDO::FETCH_ASSOC()`?

Comment: no `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: Same, `bool(false)`...

Comment: then your query is the problem

Comment: Can I use some test query to get some info about the database? Just to test if it actually works

Comment: @MacBooc Figured out the problem. Thx.